# Drools Comparison operation requires compatible types (upgrade from 5.1.1 -> 5.5.0)

Tags: java, drools

I have some Drools rules that are working fine in Drools 5.1.1 but break on upgrade to 5.5.0. Here is an example:

```
when
    Map( $limit: this["FailureLimit"] ) 
    activity: LimitExceededActivity( failureRate > $limit)
then
    ...
```

I get this error:

```
[Error: Comparison operation requires compatible types. Found float and class java.lang.Object]
[Near : {... failureRate > $limit ....}]
```

The map in this case is a HashMap<String, Number>. I get that Drools doesn't necessarily know this because of erasure, but how can I convince it that $limit is a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the answer was simply to cast in the comparison.

```
Map( $limit: this["FailureLimit"] ) 
activity: LimitExceededActivity( failureRate > (Float) $limit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too fancy, but here is a solution:

```
when
    $m: Map(this["FailureLimit"] != null) 
    LimitExceededActivity( $f: failureRate)
    $limit: Number(floatValue < $f) from $m["FailureLimit"]
then
```

Depending on your use case, the 'this["FailureLimit"] != null' in the first pattern can be removed.

The idea behind this solution is to let the 'from' pattern to do the cast for you.

Hope it helps,